# Reputation is not increasing after Copy-Editer badge

Tags: discussion, bug, edits, reputation, edit-summary

I have an issue with the Stackoverflow web site.

I managed to get "**Copy-Editor**" gold badge about
7.07AM local time(which is 1:37 AM Monday(GMT)), which will receive when you edited 500 questions.

So after that,
 I saw that normal "*Congratulations you received Copy-Editor message*" at the activity tab.
From then on , i edited few questions more, but i haven't received the  "**+2**"
reputations and "**Copy-Editor badge**" too(I know it gets time to receive badges but what's wrong with edit reputations?).following image of my Activity tab shows that **i edited 505 questions**, but reputations
stays same as it is even before i receiving the Copy-Editor badge (which is **1817**)

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation):

> You gain reputation when:
>
> - suggested edit is accepted: +2 (**up to +1000 total per user**)

500 accepted edits at 2 reputation each is 1000 rep from edits. So you've hit the limit.